# Creating a trigger but getting the unknown column error. Issues with if statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger that is fired after a row is inserted to update "m_name" to 'NOT GIVEN' if "m_name" IS NULL. But I get the error unknown column error. Also in my query, is the else statement necessary? I thought so since if m_name != null, keep m_name the same.Sorry pretty new to sql and any help is appreciated.

[image: Image of my query]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point for a trigger. A `default` value on the column does pretty much what you want:

```
create table members (
    mem_id integer not null primary key,
    f_name varchar(20) not null,
    m_name varchar(20) not null default 'NOT GIVEN',
    l_name varchar(20) not null,
    dob date
);
```

Then, you have two options when inserting.

Either you don't pass the column for insert:

```
insert into members(mem_id, f_name, l_name, dob) 
values (1, 'myName', 'lastName', current_date)
```

Or you can use `default`:

```
insert into members(mem_id, f_name, m_name, l_name, dob) 
values (1, 'myName', default, 'lastName', current_date);
```

---

*If* you really want to be able to provide an explicit `null` for insert, and assign a default value in that case, then a trigger might be necessary. I would recommend a `before insert` trigger, so you can set the default value directly before it is written:

```
delimiter //
create trigger members_no_m_name
before insert on members
for each row
begin
    if new.m_name is null
        then set new.m_name = 'NOT GIVEN';
    end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you, using new works perfectly. Though I tired to modify the column to set the constraints NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOT GIVEN'. didn't work for me... I used----            ALTER TABLE members MODIFY COLUMN m_name VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOT GIVEN';

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it in your case.

But you have to use only `SET` without `UPDATE`
But you need to refer to the column by using NEW before the column.

NEW is a Pseudo row, that has as the name says all the new data you want to enter

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER if_no_iilName 
AFTER INSERT ON menbers 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.m_name IS NULL) THEN 
    SET NEW.m_name = 'not given';
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```